# I need some help here with SQL Sum function group by dates and group

Tags: sql

I have a table called Table1

```
CaseNumber | Year  | Month | Group    | HoursAttended
1          | 2010  |   1   |   16-20  |  8
2          | 2010  |   1   |   16-20  |  1
3          | 2010  |   2   |    0-5   |  2
4          | 2009  |   4   |    0-5   |  2
4          | 2009  |   4   |  16-20   |  5
```

If I wanted to have a result like this

```
Year | Month |GroupHours| GroupHourTotal 
2010 | 1     |16-20     | 9
2010 | 3     |2         | 2
2009 | 4     |0-5       | 2
2009 | 4     |16-20     | 5
```

I tried this but I am getting incorrect results when the dates are not in the same month. 
Any ideas?

```
select Year,Month,group,hourattended,sum(hourattended)
from Table1
groupby Year,Month,hourattended,sum(hourattended)
order by year desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Year,Month,group,sum(hourattended)
from Table1
groupby Year,Monthorder by year desc
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't group by hourattended

```
select Year,Month,group,sum(hourattended) grouphourtotal
from Table1
group by Year,Month,group
order by year desc, month desc
```

This must be pseudo, otherwise quote the "group" column name as required

Answer (score 2):

Only group by the columns that are not aggregates in the result set. Since you're summing HoursAttended, it does not belong in your GROUP BY.

`select Year,Month,group,hourattended,sum(hourattended)
from Table1
groupby Year,Month
order by year desc`

Answer (score 1):

You have a dependent field, Group, which needs to be broken into a separate table. Once you do that, it's a piece of cake:

> SELECT Year, Month, GroupTitle,
>   SUM(HoursAttended) As HoursAttended
>   From Cases C JOIN Groups G ON
>   C.GroupId = G.Id GROUP BY Year, Month,
>   GroupTitle ORDER BY year desc

Replace "Group" with "GroupId", make it a foreign key to a Groups table, and Bob's your uncle.